# Extracting interpolated data along a line between 2 points of a scalar located at nodes of a 2-D unstructured mesh

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, data-analysis

I have a csv of data in the following form:

| x-coordinate | y-coordinate | scalar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.2344 |
| 0.1 | 0.25 | 12.588 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 0.65 | 0.8 | 0.4438 |
| 1 | 1 | 12.5 |

This data is from a simulation performed on an unstructured grid.

I want to define 2 points p1 & p2, and extract the scalar values along a line drawn between p1 & p2.

My p1 and p2 will be picked in such a way that either the x or the y will remain constant along the line, (the lines will always be longitudinal or latitudinal: example: p1(x=0, y=0.5) & p2(x=1, y=0.5). Since we are working with data located in an unstructured manner, the points on the line may fall between points from the original grid.

I, then, want to plot my varying coordinate vs my scalar (x-coordinate vs scalar in the above example).

I have been reading about interpolation tools provided in SciPy, but I cannot seem to find a way to do exactly what I have in mind.

I am looking for some direction in what tools/methods/approaches I can use/take to get this done.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

I tried using LinearNDInterpolate and NearestNDInterpolate to interpolate the data onto a structured grid then extracting a subset from it, but my data is from an adaptive mesh that has been refined locally in areas of interest. A structured grid that encompasses the entire domain misses out on the finer details within these areas of interest.

Comment: are you trying to interpolate a line `(x, y)` or a surface `(x, y, scalar)` ?

Comment: @D.L The original data is in the form (x, y, scalar), I want to extract a 1-D slice through this surface between points p1 and p2. Since the original grid is unstructured, my slice/line may pass between points in the original grid. In that case, I will need to interpolate between the nearest points of the the original grid. Hope this explanation makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have a **surface** in that respect and **not just a single line**.

you can use `scipy` for the interpolation like this:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

def interpolate_z(df, x, y):
    # x, y, and z coordinates of the dataframe
    xi = df['x'].values
    yi = df['y'].values
    zi = df['z'].values

    # Interpolate the value of z
    result = griddata((xi, yi), zi, (x, y), rescale=True)
    return result
```

You then have to create a surface to interpolate. Here is an example surface (`meshgrid`) that you could use:

```py
# dataframe containing a surface
def surface_df():
    # Define the x and y coordinates of the surface
    x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

    # Create a grid of x and y coordinates
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    # Define the function of the surface
    Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2))

    # Create a DataFrame from the grid and function
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':X.ravel(), 'y':Y.ravel(), 'z':Z.ravel()})

    # Print the DataFrame
    print(df)

    return df
```

...and then the final part to test the code:

```py
df = surface_df()

x = 2.5
y = 1.5
result = interpolate_z(df, x, y)
print(result)
```

with my example numbers and the example surface, i get this:

```
0.22371169675502225
```